# How can I ensure migration YAML files execute in specified dependency order?

Tags: 8, migrations, configuration, importing-exporting

### EDIT: To Answer my own question...

I ended up making multiple migration files like this:

1. Node Type A Part 1 (most fields migrated except the ones that need to reference Node Type B)
2. Node Type B
3. Node Type A Part 2 (now you can add the field referencing Node Type B)
4. etc.

[Here's a Github link to my finalized set of real-world migration files](https://github.com/Doomd/Drupal8CustomMigration) which illustrate how I broke up my migration into different sequential parts. Good luck!

---

### Original Question:

My Drupal migration yaml files are not being imported in the correct execution order.

I have [8 migration files](https://github.com/Doomd/D8MigrationOrder), most that depend on another file being executed first. I'm
using a Google Spreadsheet as the source, and targeting Drupal 8.9+. I have tagged all my dependencies, and all was going well with my test imports (`using drush migrate:import --tag="Rooster Business"`) and the corresponding rollback commands. But at some point, after adding a few fields, the migrations began to fail because they were being executed out of order (particularly my business_locations and business_offers migrations).

Here's the exact error:

```
[error]  Migration rooster_node_business_offers did not meet the requirements. 
Missing migrations rooster_node_business_location. requirements: rooster_node_business_location.
```

The new fields themselves don't fail, so it's not that (I wouldn't think). I think I have correctly set up the dependencies in all the files, but they are NOT being respected (at least not completely).

**I have tried the following:**

- Alphabetizing all the migration id's and filenames (to order them by desired import execution order).
- Dropping all migration tables from the database and doing full cache refresh
- Changing the last file I want executed (`rooster_node_business_offers`) to use "optional" dependencies instead of "required." (This causes the failure to go away, but then some of the desired field values are missing from the migration).
- Uninstalling and reinstalling the entire custom migration module.
- I've tried just migrating the "last" migration with `drush migrate:import rooster_node_business_offers --execute-dependencies` command which should in theory execute all the files in order as they all depend in a chain on each other. No dice. I get the same error: `[error]  Migration rooster_node_business_offers did not meet the requirements...`

None of these attempts have solved the problem. I have a theory that it has something to do with the fields names of the sources (because I think I may have changed a few of them, and have definitely added quite a few). But that still doesn't account for why the migrations are not respecting the dependency order.

**Bottom line: I have two questions:**

1. Why are the last two migration files (rooster_node_business_location & rooster_node_business_offers) not being executed in order by dependency (and how can I fix this)?
2. If that is not an easy to answer question, what is the logic of the "default" ordering, and how can I game that logic so I can still get my migration files to execute in the desired order?

Here is the order I'd LIKE to have the migrations to execute in:

```
rooster_file_bg_photo
rooster_file_logo
rooster_users
rooster_file_logo_to_media
rooster_file_bg_photo_to_media
rooster_node_parent_business
rooster_node_business_location
rooster_node_business_offers
```

And here is the order that they are actually being migrated in (same as the order displayed after entering the `drush ms` command:

```
  Rooster (Rooster)   rooster_file_bg_photo            Idle
  Rooster (Rooster)   rooster_file_logo                Idle
  Rooster (Rooster)   rooster_users                    Idle
  Rooster (Rooster)   rooster_file_logo_to_media       Idle
  Rooster (Rooster)   rooster_file_bg_photo_to_media   Idle
  Rooster (Rooster)   rooster_node_parent_business     Idle
  Rooster (Rooster)   rooster_node_business_offers     Idle
  Rooster (Rooster)   rooster_node_business_location   Idle
```

I've made a repository of my exact migration files (and I've only redacted the Google Spreadsheet URLs). [Here are all the migration files on Github.](https://github.com/Doomd/D8MigrationOrder)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: A migration can't be optional if you use its ID in this migration with `migration_lookup`. And you have a circular dependency between your last two migrations.

Comment: It was my understanding that migrations that need data from a migration that come afterwards will create stubs and then insert that data once the migration becomes available. As a matter of fact, this has worked in my migrations when the migrations were executed in order. Do you know how I can at least get the migrations to execute in the order I want?

Comment: I just commented out the migration_lookup fields that required subsequent migrations. But now my nodes don't have references to each other. Is there a way to write a few additional YAML files that import/process these reference fields (this time, after the requisite migrations) without overwriting the values of all the other previously imported fields? For example, Can Migration #1A with Fields A-C be imported, then Migration #2 which depends on Migration #1A, THEN Migration #1B with field D (which depends on Migration #2)? Basically, I'd like some migration files to UPDATE, not overwrite.

Comment: Simply specify `nid` (or uid key in case of user entity) in the `process` section of migration #1B, e.g. through a `migration_lookup` or `entity_lookup`, then you can update an existing entity.

Comment: @Hudri Thanks for you're help...but I'm still facing problems. I tried to do both a migration_lookup and an entity_lookup: ([see file 074_rooster_node_parent_business2](https://gist.github.com/Doomd/458d38ab34a4266003cc5cf0cff5d971)), and I get an error after all the other migrations get processed (`rooster_node_parent_business2 Migration - 9 failed`). I'm sure I set it up wrong, but I there's little documentation on migrating additional fields into the same previously migrated content all in the same migration group/tag...

Comment: So, I did some more research. As I suspected, you ARE allowed to reference migration_lookups for migrations that are imported afterwards. BUT, there is a bug. The id of the migration file needed in subsequent references has to be in REVERSE alphabetical order: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3024634

Comment: @Doomd were you able to resolve the with unmet dependency even though its present ? If yes, can you pls share the solution ?

Comment: @miststudent2011 I will have to go back and look at the exact migration files, but I recall that I just made another file that basically filled in the missing lookups after the dependancy was filled in. So...if part of A needs to lookup something populated by B, make a C file that runs after B is complete. I'll share my files after I get into work. Cheers.

Comment: @miststudent2011FYI, I updated my question with a link to a github repo I just created with all my finalized migration files. You'll notice that I broke up the migration into two parts for two different node types because I wanted them to reference each other. Hope that helps

Comment: @Doomd thanks for the update but it seems URL to the GIT repo is wrong. I was able to solve the issue I will add my solution to this question so others can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the migration dependency unmet error.

Here is my approach to resolve the issue.

For example you have three migrations `migration_a` , `migration_b` and `migration_c` , and `migration_a` is dependent on `migration_b` and `migration_b` is dependent on `migration_c`.

What you have to do is define `migration_b` as optional dependency in `migration_a` and similarly define `migration_c` as optional dependency in `migration_a`  .

Then import the `migration_c` manually first with the command `drush mim migration_c` and later `migration_b` with command `drush mim migration_b` and finally `drush mim migration_a`

Thus you have your migration imported.

Please let me know if you have any additional suggestions to resolve the issue.

---

There are other solutions which are scattered across the drupal.org to resolve the issue but they did not help me to resolve the issue.

1. Name the migrations in the alphabetical order respective to their migration order.
2. Check whether the line is defined `$settings['cache']['default'] = 'cache.backend.null';` relevant [bug](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2878858)