# How to migrate PDF files to specific node

Tags: database, files, drush, migrations

I have a directory with PDF files and I have 45 nodes of content type **Download**. I have to migrate each PDF file to specific node. All PDF file names I read from a CSV. Before these PDF files, I had to migrate title **(drupal default field)** , external title and a checkbox field to each node. I did it successfully, but migrating PDF files is I guess different and a lot more difficult.

Here is my code for migrating PDF files

```
id: program_files
label: Migrating files for Download content type.
migration_tags:
  - file
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: 'modules/custom/csv_migration/sources/downloads.csv'
  header_row_count: 1
  ids: [constants/file_source_uri]
  keys:
    - PLACEMENTPATH
  fields:
    0:
      name: field_document_file
      label: 'Download file'
  constants:
    file_source_uri: [public://import/program]
    file_dest_uri: ['public://download/files']
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:file'
process:
  file_source:
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: /
      source: [constants/file_source_uri, PLACEMENTPATH]
  file_dest:
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: /
      source: [constants/file_dest_uri, PLACEMENTPATH]
  filename: PLACEMENTPATH
  uri:
    -
      plugin: file_copy
      source:
        - '@file_source'
        - '@file_dest'
```

Once I run command drush ms it displays me migration id **(program_files)**, but after that when I run drush mim program_files, it throws the error like this.

```
In Connection.php line 744:
                                                                                            
  Placeholders must have a trailing [] if they are to be expanded with an array of values.
```

The thing I notice once I start **drush mim program_files** is that directory **download** is created in **sites/default/files**, since I defined that in YML, but no files are transfered.

What am I doing wrong? Please, help.

Comment: I hate to say it, but for just 45 files, it's probably faster to manually create the nodes and upload the PDFs than to troubleshoot a migration.

Comment: +1 @PatrickKenny , have been trying to solve issue with migration from the past two weeks https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/299395/ still not able to resolve it.